# How can I connect to and read data from the Zebra RFD90 Reader using React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, sdk, zebra-scanners

I have a Zebra Bluetooth RFD90 Reader. I want to connect this device to my React Native project and read data from it. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Do you have any suggestions?
React Native Version [0.71.4]

Comment: These devices generally have multiple ways in which they can configured.  I would suggest looking up the white paper and the SPP communication guides on the zebra website and work through them.   Since you're connecting, you're most likely just not setting the delimiter correctly, these are usually `\r` by default, while the bluetooth library is `\n` by default.

Comment: Take a look on the sdk: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/rfid-sdk-for-android.html.